# Escape pipe-character in org-mode

Tags: emacs, escaping, org-mode, tabular

I've got a table in Emacs [org-mode](http://orgmode.org/), and the contents are regular expressions.  I can't seem to figure out how to escape a literal pipe-character (`|`) that's part of a regex though, so it's interpreted as a table-cell separator.  Could someone point me to some help?  Thanks.

**Update**: I'm also looking for escapes for a slash (`/`), so that it doesn't trigger the start of an italic/emphasis sequence.  I experimented with `\/` and `\//` - for example, suppose I want the literal text `/foo/` in a table cell.  Here are 3 ways of attempting it:

```
| /foo/ | \/foo/ | \//foo/ |
```

In LaTeX export, that becomes:

```
\emph{foo}  &  \/foo/  &  \//foo/
```

So none of them is the plain `/foo/` I'm hoping for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to insert "|" in org-mode table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876048/how-to-insert-in-org-mode-table)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`\vert` for the pipe.

Forward slashes seem to work fine for me unescaped when exporting both to HTML and PDF.

Comment: Great!  I'm also using braces for things like `a\vert{}b`, as otherwise it would be `a\vertb` and not work.  As found on http://orgmode.org/worg/org-symbols.html .

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce my weirdness of 2 different exports for slashes (so I edited that out of my question), but I added an example of trying to get literal slashes and not achieving it.

Comment: But apparently this only affects the exported document, but not how the cell content is interpreted as a string. OP says the pipe character is part of a regexp, and I assumed he/she needs to use this regexp in a formula, say `$4='(if (string-match $1 $2) "Yes" "No")`, but this does not work.

Comment: Like  a  \vert  b.There should be spaces on it's either side.

Answer (score 11):

Use a broken-bar character, “`¦`”, Unicode 00A6 BROKEN BAR. This may or may not work for your specific needs, but it’s a good visual approximation.

Answer (score 1):

You could also format the relevant text as *verbatim* or *code*:

> Text in the code and verbatim string is not processed for Org mode
>   specific syntax; it is exported verbatim.

So you might try something like `=foo | bar=` (code) or `foo ~|~ bar` (verbatim).  It does change the output format, though.

Comment: Doesn't help for tables. My regex `/(foo|bar)/` turns into two table cells, even when surrounded by `~` characters. Have to write it as `/(foo\vert{}bar)/`. Too bad, because I'm using org-mode (in this case) for tracking my development notes, not for exporting to PDF or LaTeX or anything. Oh well.

Comment: Ooh, but I did just find a (sort-of) solution; will post as an answer.