# how to insert "|" in org-mode table

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have some trouble in using org-mode. I want create a table in org-mode like this:

```
| operator | use         |
|----------+-------------|
|   |      | expr | expr |
```

but when I press TAB, the table changed like this:

```
| operator | use |      |      |
|----------+-----+------+------|
|          |     | expr | expr |.
```

How to avoid it?

Answer (score 25):

> To insert a vertical bar into a table field, use \vert or, inside a word abc\vert{}def.

Source: [Org-mode manual: The built-in table editor](http://orgmode.org/manual/Built_002din-table-editor.html#fn-1).

If `\vert` is not automatically converted to `|`, call `org-toggle-pretty-entities`, per:

> <kbd>C-c C-x \</kbd>
>
> Toggle display of entities as UTF-8 characters. This does not change the buffer content which remains plain ASCII, but it overlays the UTF-8 character for display purposes only.

Source: [Org-mode manual: Special symbols](http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-symbols.html#Special-symbols)

The function `org-toggle-pretty-entities` was introduced in [version 7.01](http://orgmode.org/Changes_old.html#sec-12-2-3). Call `org-version` and upgrade Org-mode if necessary.

Comment: I can't find org-toggle-pretty-entities in my elisp, I use Emacs23.3. Maybe I must install something else?

Comment: There should be spaces on "\vert" either side. Like a \vert b.It works for me. Emacs 24.5.1 (Org mode 8.3.5)

Answer (score 4):

Using some unicode seems to work relatively well.  I got these 2 characters to work: `¦ ǀ`
There is also this one: `∣` which just gave a unicode box.  Your milage will vary.

sindikat's answer above is more correct, but if you want a vertical bar that looks pretty in your org source file, and you use UTF-8 (or similar) then this is an option.

Answer (score -4):

If you just want to insert a new column, just type 'M-S right'.